# 2008 VW Jetta AC blower/Wiper fluid/12v charger working intermittently

Tags: vw, ac

The AC and heat cool just fine but the blower comes on intermittently and now doesn't work at all.  The 12v charger doesn't charge and the wiper fluid won't spray.  When I try to get the wiper fluid to spray the AC stops cooling and I have to turn off the AC and back on again for it to begin cooling.  I have checked fuses and as far as I can tell they are all fine.  Any idea?

Comment: How are you making out with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Statistically, I would look at the ground termination area under the battery.  At least it is under the battery on many Jetta's, although I have not worked on a 2008.

The relay for the AC control, including the condenser fan is under that ground point.

While you are at it, check the battery ground to the bell housing.  One Jetta presented with weird electrical problems, and the 13mm nut clamping ground to the bell housing was suspiciously loose.